# How to load javascript on another webpage through XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss

I am working on a school assignment. There are a few tasks I need to complete that I've been stuck on for quite sometime now. These goals are a little more complicated then the problem I will lay out but, it will solve the underlying issue that I can't seem to figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Essentially, I have an html file and there is a vulnerable fake website hosted on my VM. It is essentially a login page through the iceweasel web browser. I have found the vulnerability as one of the fields simply echoes the post value. The user opens my page and it simple makes a post request to the fake website and I insert the script inside the value property of said input. Which looks something like this:

```
<input type="someType" name="someName" value=""/><script>alert('Hello');</script>">
```

The problem I am having is that this alert is happening on my webpage and I want it to execute the alert after the vulnerable webpage is loaded. Does anyone know how to accomplish such a feat?

**Edit Part3(Solved 2 myself finally):**

Once I followed your suggestion of escaping the double quotes and < and > signs I was able to successfully get the alert to execute on the vulnerable web page. I was also successful in sending a function through the script(Part2) it was another syntax error.

For the next part I am dealing with is that I don't want the user to see the "> that is printed to the page when it loads. Is there a way to get rid of that text?

For example:

```
<input type="someType" name="someName" 
value=""&quot;/&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt;"/>
```

the "> is printed to the page. How do I get rid of that/hide it?

Comment: I'm sending a POST form to the website with the above input.

Comment: ... and you just XSS-ed _yourself_, by not properly escaping the value of the input field in your own form.

Comment: @misorude do I need to escape the 2nd quote with something like &quot;?

Comment: Yes, and the `<` and `>` _should_ be escaped as well.

Comment: @misorude Thank you for the suggestion. Mind taking a look at my second problem? I've been stuck for a few hours now lol

Comment: In your last example, there’s one `"` to much, `value=""&quot;`. And if you don’t want to see the field value, use `type=hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You have more quotes than needed at the beginning of the assignment, as @misorude mentioned.  If you keep the type=text, your fake website is gonna show a text rectangle for a few miliseconds prior the transition. Hide it (type=hidden).